# How to append a new disk to an existing folder

Tags: linux, rsync, symlink, storage

I have a server with a program which rapidly writes data to a folder. I attached a new disk to the server, mounted it and now I want it to expand or replace the folder with data. The program works with hardcoded folder names and I don't really want to stop it copy the files to new disk and symlink them to address of the old folder.

My original way would be like this:

```
rsync -avxP --progress /data/oldsrc /mnt/newsrc/
rm -rf /data/oldsrc
ln -s /mnt/newsrc /data/oldsrc
```

Is there any way to do this without moving/copying old files, removing them from source and linking from new disk to old folder?

Edit: I need all the data in the old folder to be accessible by the program.

Comment: Can't you unmount `/data/oldsrc/`and mount `/mnt/newsrc` instead?

Comment: @Panki i need all the data inside the old folder accessible. Editing my question.

Comment: Is it an LVM filesystem structure? Kindly post the output of `df -Th`.

Comment: @erTugRul nah it's an EXT4 drive.

```/dev/sda3                         ext4      309G  286G  6,6G  98% /```